# How to fix 'An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause' error in MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql

For a school project, i need to create some databases in MS SQL Server , create some views, and manage the users acces. The thing is that our course was really empty, and i'm having trouble with some mechanics of MS SQL Server

I have a table with every player of the football world cup of 2018, and i want to take the 20 shortest players, so i just wanted to use ORDER BY Person.Height. If i use that, my result is something like that :

```
62    165    Panama    QA19
63    165    SaudiArabia    AY8
78    165    Switzerland SX23
59    166    Mexico    AJ20
etc...
```

but i just want to take the shortest players and order them by country, not by height, so having something like that

```
69    168    Argentina   SE18
66    168    Argentina   LM15
67    166    Brazil    CF22
64    169    Brazil    RF18
```

the 20 shortest players ordered by country in an alphabetical order

This is the code i have right now, and this give me the first result

```
SELECT TOP (20) Person.Weight, Person.Height, Country.NameCountry,                     
LEFT(Person.Name, 1)+LEFT(Person.FirstName, 1)+CAST(Player.Numero AS 
nvarchar(MAX)) AS Initiales

FROM Person INNER JOIN Country 
ON Person.CountryId = Country.CountryID 
INNER JOIN Player 
ON Person.PersonID = Player.PersonID

WHERE -----------------
ORDER BY Person.Height, Country.NameCountry
```

If i use MIN(Person.Height) in the WHERE clause, i have this error : **An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.**
But i don't need any HAVING OR GROUP BY clause, so i don't really understand what i'm supposed to do. 
I know that my explanation is not very clear, but if somebody could help me with that, that would be vey nice

Comment: This not looks like mysql.

Comment: `SELECT TOP (20)`? Are you actually asking about MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it's MS SQL Server, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Person.Weight, Person.Height, Country.NameCountry,                     
    LEFT(Person.Name, 1)+LEFT(Person.FirstName, 1)+CAST(Player.Numero AS 
    nvarchar(MAX)) AS Initiales
    FROM Person INNER JOIN Country 
    ON Person.CountryId = Country.CountryID 
    INNER JOIN Player 
    ON Person.PersonID = Player.PersonID
    WHERE -----------------
    ORDER BY Person.Height
    LIMIT 0,20)
ORDER NameCountry
```